# Is it Possible to get the header and footer from a PDF document using IText?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I'm merging two separate PDF files into a single PDF file, using IText. But the problem is i need to replace the headers and footers of first page in all the pages. Is it possible to segregate the header , footer and the body content of the PDF  Itext ?

I'm using Itext 5

So far I have done

```
 PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\generatedSample.pdf");
 PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\tobeconv.pdf");

 Document document = new Document();
    document.addHeader("Header Text", "");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\MergeFile.pdf");
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, fos);
    document.open();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
    Phrase phrase;
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
    Font font = new Font(bf, 9);
    int n = reader1.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader1.getNumberOfPages(); i++) 
    {
        page = copy.getImportedPage(reader1, i);
        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
        // phrase = new Phrase("page"+i+"of "+n,font);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getOverContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, null, 520, 5, 0);
        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader2.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

        page = copy.getImportedPage(reader2, i);
        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
        // phrase = new Phrase("page " + (n + i), font);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getOverContent(), 
     Element.ALIGN_CENTER, null, 520, 5, 0);
        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Which iText version do you use?

Also what do you mean by override? Do you want to refact some content from the resultant pdf? Could you explain it, preferably with some examples?

Comment: Also please could you show us what you have written so far?

Comment: By what criteria can your headers and footers be recognized as such? As soon as you detail them, we're can tell you whether they can be implemented for itext.

Comment: @mkl the header will be a logo and the footer will have copyright details

Comment: *"the header will be a logo"* - By logo you mean some bitmap image? Or some vector image? Or some text drawn in some fancy font? Or a combination thereof? And whichever it is, the same does not occur somewhere else on the pages? *"the footer will have copyright details"* - To recognize how? And something similar won't appear elsewhere on the pages?